# Retrieving parameter from sql table to use in procedure

Tags: sql-server, procedure

I have this procedure in SQL Server to check if word exists in table, if exist update table, if not add word into table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE raw_add @word nvarchar (100)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Connection.dbo.Dict WHERE game + '%' LIKE @word + '%')
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Dict SET count=count+1 WHERE game + '%' LIKE @word + '%'
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Dict (mongol) VALUES (@word)
        END
END
```

I can execute procedure.

```
EXECUTE raw_add 'dota'
```

But rather than typing every single word, I want to take words in another table as parameters for procedure. I have this code, but getting no parameter was supplied error.

```
EXECUTE raw_add SELECT words_to_add
FROM Connection.dbo.raw p
CROSS APPLY string_split(p.words_to_add, ' ')
```

Comment: No you can't do that use table type parameter/XML  in SP instead.

Comment: Your stored procedure only accepts one value of type nvarchar(100), how would you expect to pass multiple words that exceed 100 characters? I would change your Procedure to accept a parameter of type XML and populate it with all the words you want to insert or update, then pass that to the procedure

Comment: If your words are in another table, you can do this inside the stored procedure, can't you?  Then, you may not have to parse the parameters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do `exec <procedure> select <parameters>`, and even if you code, that would make little sense because it would be [RBAR](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/) - meaning you will run your procedure Row By Agonizing Row (Acronym source: [Jeff Moden](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/4020758?fullName=Jeff%20Moden)).

What you need to do is write a new procedure, that will do the upsert with a set based apporach.

SQL Server has a [`Merge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) command for upserts that you can use for that.

```
DECLARE @words AS TABLE (word nvarchar(100))

INSERT INTO @words (word)
-- assuming that's the name of the column from the string split
SELECT /*perhaps DISTINCT here?*/ Item 
FROM Connection.dbo.raw p
CROSS APPLY string_split(p.words_to_add, ' ')

MERGE Connection.dbo.Dict  AS target  
USING (SELECT word FROM @words) AS source (word) 
    ON (target.game LIKE '%' + source.word + '%')  
WHEN MATCHED THEN   
    UPDATE SET count += 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT (mongol)  
    VALUES (source.word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below way to get your requirement.

```
DECLARE @word varchar(50);
    Declare AIX Cursor for 
    SELECT words_to_add FROM dbo.raw p
    --SELECT  column FROM  database.dbo.table1;
    Open AIX;
    Fetch Next from AIX into  @word;
    -- this will produce for example, 100 results
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    IF (@word IS Not NULL) 
        exec raw_add @word
    FETCH NEXT FROM AIX 
        INTO @word;
    END
    CLOSE AIX;
    DEALLOCATE AIX;
```

Comment: A Cursor is usually the wrong tool to use, since it can only do RBAR. A set based solution is almost always better then using a cursor.